# placing conditions in a join query join on vs where

Tags: performance, join, query-performance

Is there and advantage to one of the following options over the other or are they the same ?

```
select * 
from T1 
Join T2 
   on T2.id=T1.t2_id 
   and T2.field=value;
```

vs.

```
select * 
from T1 
Join T2 
  on T2.id=T1.t2_id 
where T2.field=value;
```

And in general - are there performance (dis)advantages to placing the conditions within the JOIN ON statement as opposed to the WHERE statement ?

Comment: Try them out and check the query plan. AFAIK SQL Server treats both as the same

Comment: The execution plan will be exactly the same. I don't recommend placing conditions in joins though. If you or any other developer decides to change the INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN they might be surpirised that the query works differently.

Comment: @Łukasz Kastelik can you please explain what would be the difference if we change to a left join please ?

Comment: @epeleg I can try to do it but I suggest you read the following post (at least the 2 top answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018952/condition-within-join-or-where

Comment: Thanks, that was a realy good pointer.I read all of them and found the third one (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1019432/25412) to be the most informative IMHO.
I wrote an answer to my own Q based on that Answer.

Answer (score 4):

When using inner joins there is no semantic difference between the two, and it would usually be make sense to put join related conditions in the `JOIN` and filtering ones in the `WHERE` clause.

However, when using outer joins the semantics are not the same.
for example: in a left join - rows from the left table will be returned even if there the `JOIN ON` includes some limitation on the fields from right table that are not met. but if the same limitation would be moved to the `WHERE` clause - the (already Left Joined) row from the left table that has no matching row on the right table will be discarded.

So for `INNER JOIN` - it does not matter - for `OUTER JOIN` - you should think what exactly do you want to get.

Note that in some cases this is actually desirable. 
e.g. - In Queries such as:

```
SELECT *   
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.id = T1.t2_id   
WHERE T2.id IS NULL ;
```